# How destination mail server can know the DKIM selector

Tags: dkim, opendkim

It is possible to set a "subdomain" in DKIM DNS record name.
This "subdomain" is called a selector. It allows to have multiple DKIM keys for the same domain.

There is something I do not understand during the DKIM verification.

Let's suppose Bob sends a mail to Alice. How Alice mailserver should know this selector ? This selector is not shown in DMARC record (and anywhere else) so how destination mail server can know the selector name ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It's contained in the DKIM header.

Example:

> DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=**example.com**; s=**default**;

This corresponds to the txt record under the following DNS record:

> **default**._domainkey.**example.com**

Answer (score 2):

The DKIM-Signature header
field in the e-mail message itself  contains the selector used  (as well as the d= domain) as a mandatory part of the signature / header:

[RFC 6376](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376.html#section-3.5)

> ```
> s= The selector subdividing the namespace for the "d=" (domain) tag
>   (plain-text; REQUIRED).
>
>   Internationalized selector names MUST be encoded as A-labels, as
>   described in Section 2.3 of [RFC5890].
>
>   ABNF:
>
>   sig-s-tag    = %x73 [FWS] "=" [FWS] selector
> ```

> ```
>   ...
> ```

> ```
>     INFORMATIVE EXAMPLE of a signature header field spread across
>     multiple continuation lines:
>
>    DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; d=example.net; s=brisbane;
>       c=simple; q=dns/txt; i=@eng.example.net;
>       t=1117574938; x=1118006938;
>       h=from:to:subject:date;
>       z=From:foo@eng.example.net|To:joe@example.com|
>        Subject:demo=20run|Date:July=205,=202005=203:44:08=20PM=20-0700;
>       bh=MTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTI=;
>       b=dzdVyOfAKCdLXdJOc9G2q8LoXSlEniSbav+yuU4zGeeruD00lszZVoG4ZHRNiYzR
> ```

which the corresponds to a `brisbane._domainkey.example.net` DNS record

Answer (score 2):

For 5,000+ domains, you can look up the domain on [registry.prove.email](https://registry.prove.email), and if someone has contributed it before, you can get the DKIM selectors for that domain and historical DKIM key values. In real time, you'd be able to hit DNS, but for past emails, you'd need to hit a historical registry like this.

Comment: Mail servers don't need historical records.

Comment: It's nice to have historical DKIM keys, since then you can verify old emails!

Comment: The receiving server verifies the message when it arrives and adds authentication results. I don't really see why anyone would need to get back to it later. If that was a thing, the receiving server would have added a copy of the DKIM key into the headers, too.

Comment: You might want to prove receipt of the email after the fact, for instance for whistleblowing or as a receipt.

Answer (score 0):

The selector is on the `DKIM-Signature` header that is added to the email by the signer, along with the signing domain identifier (SDID).

The selector is on the `s=` tag and, together with the domain in the `d=` tag, you have everything you need to look up the record on the DNS.

> This selector is not shown in DMARC record

The selector should be present in the `<record><auth_results><dkim><selector>...</selector></dkim></auth_results></record>` element. Although I wonder why a reporting server would leave the selector out, its presence is not a strict requirement.

Comment: I have no DKIM-Signature header in the mail I am sending. But DKIM verification is still working ! Do you think some mail server looks at default selector by default ? Thanks

Comment: When one is setting up DKIM one must choose a selector to use on one's email software, _and_ configure DNS accordingly. There's no default value for the selector. If your emails are being signed somehow, that's because some server along the way is doing it. Debugging this is simple: check the domain (`d=`) tag on the signature headers, and you'll see the DNS domain name that added the signature.